# How do I change xdg applications with Terminal=true in .desktop to open in something else than xterm?

Tags: release-hera, settings, pantheon-terminal, app-shortcuts

TLDR: I want to run Midnight Commander as default File manager, I need to know how to change default terminal for `Terminal=true` from xterm to anything else. pantheon-terminal seems to be not suitable.

So now I've set midnight commander as my default File manager but it keeps opening in xterm. I cannot find a way to change it to elementary terminal emulator anywhere.

I've loosely rgrep'd `/usr/share` directory but could not find anything relevant, same for `/etc`.

`update-alternatives` lists default terminal emulator as `io.elementary.terminal` so the problem shouldn't be there.

Also when I run `io.elementary.terminal --new-window --execute=mc` it opens new window AND new tab (two tabs total: one with shell, other with `mc`). Besides that I cannot be sure how it handles spaces in path names to add the command directly to the `Exec=` line. Should I write elementary terminal off completely?

When the elementary terminal starts like that it reports its height as 1 row, because of that mc quits and reports that it does not support that height. It seems that whatever I do it always starts a shell.

versions:

```
mc/bionic,now 3:4.8.19-1 amd64 [installed]
pantheon-terminal/bionic,now 5.5.1+r1640+pkg72~ubuntu5.1.2.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

Comment: The edit in the answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/492897/how-to-set-midnight-commander-as-the-default-file-manager) looks right/promising. I've never tried it, so can't say it is certainly correct.

Comment: @KGIII As I said, it opens new window with two tabs and mc fails to start because terminal height is reported as 1. I want to open one tab in new window that will close after I quit mc

Answer (score 0):

Install deepin-terminal

`sudo apt install -y deepin-terminal`

Change default deepin-terminal theme to `tango`

Create the file `~/.local/share/applications/mc.desktop` with contents

`[Desktop Entry]
Name=Midnight Commander
MimeType=inode/directory
Exec=deepin-terminal -e mc %F
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=FileManager`

[Answer based on](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/492897/how-to-set-midnight-commander-as-the-default-file-manager)